# Using different intonations with Watson text to speech

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am developing a PoC using Watson text to speech and Watson conversation.

Sometimes, the chatbot needs to ask a question, so I'd like text to speech to synthesize the voice using an interrogation intonation.

Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watson Text to Speech supports SSML, and has expressive SSML tags.

The one you want to use is `Uncertainty`. As it is defined as *"conveys an uncertain, interrogative message"*.

Example:

```
<express-as type="Uncertainty">
  Could she still be in the office? She told me that she might leave early.
</express-as>
```

More details on it's usage is here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/text-to-speech/SSML-expressive.html#the-express-as-element

Comment: Hi Simon. Not for all voices. I am using Isabela's voice (PT-BR), which is the only voice in Brazillian Portuguese available,which does not seem to support SSML tags. However, since my question is obviously incomplete (I haven't mentioned which voice I was using) and since your answer actually is the right answer, I will accept it and close this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly use text-to-speech (TTS) for output and speech-to-text (STT) for input. You would need to use a middleware or app layer to drive the conversation and route the input/output to the other services (see ["how to use" in the docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#how-to-use-the-service)).

I have used the following [TJBot](https://ibmtjbot.github.io/) recipe as a simple and good started for some projects: https://github.com/damiancummins/tell_the_time

Comment: Hi. I am sorry, maybe I was not clear. My question is regarding TTS support to generate audio with the correct intonation for questions.

Comment: With the TTS service you can generate the correct intonation (I have done that for some English words in German). But again, the TTS is another component that needs to be coordinated via an app or middleware layer.

Comment: I am using the Brazilian Portuguese voice and it seems to ignore the question mark in the end of the statement

Comment: I am trying with the TTS demo and it seems that for some voices, the question mark is correctly interpreted (such as Allison). I believe voices have different SSML support, and probably Isabela has no support for it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Concatenative TTS may have problems to create correct intonation in questions. If you think it happens consistently or too often please open a bug. 
If you have a specific question which gets incorrect intonation try to rephrase it a little bit if possible. A useful trick for this voice could be to use double question mark '??'

Comment: hey, nice tip! gonna try!